# Daemon for file watching / reporting in the whole UNIX OS

Tags: linux, perl, file, unix

I have to write a Unix/Linux daemon, which should watch for particular set of files (e.g. `*.log`) in any of the file directories, across various locations and report it to me. Then I have to read all the newly modified files and then I have to process them and push grepped data into Elasticsearch.

Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

I tried various Perl modules (e.g. `File::ChangeNotify`, `File::Monitor`) but for these I need to specify the directories, which I don't want: I need the list of files to be dynamically generated and I also need the content.

Is there any method that I can call OS system calls for file creation and then read the newly generated/modified file?

Comment: Why is this tagged with _redis_? Also, Perl module names are _case-sensitive_. There is no `FILE` namespace on CPAN.

Comment: [File::Monitor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AMonitor) has a `recurse` option.

Comment: @simbabque the reason i tagged redis is that i have to push all the grepped data from logs to redis and then to elastic search

Comment: @reinierpost can you give me snippet which suffices my requirement ?

Comment: @Shantesh but that is not relevant to your question. You should try to formulate a [mcve] also for questions that are more the theory kind. Don't expect people to just do your job for you and write code. That's not what Stack Overflow is for. If you want that, hire an agency.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for your inputs, have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

Not as easy as it sounds unfortunately. You have hooks to [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) (on some platforms) that let you trigger an event on a particular inode changing.

But for wider scope changing, you're really talking about audit and accounting tracking - this isn't a small topic though - not a lot of people do auditing, and there's a reason for that. It's complicated and very platform specific (even different versions of Linux do it differently). Your favourite search engine should be able to help you find answers relevant to your platform.

It may be simpler to run a scheduled task in `cron` - but not too frequently, because spinning a filesystem like that is dirty - along with `File::Find` or similar to just run a search occasionally.